# How many identical rectangles, with a length of twice the width, can be cut off with this paper?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

> > We have a paper with dimensions 300 mm in 210 mm.  We can cut off with this paper to identical rectangles, with a length of twice the width. What is the largest area of such a rectangle?

Comment: You're missing something.  Since there are no restrictions on size, the answer to your first question is "arbitrarily large."

Comment: I think the question isn't complete. As is the answer to the first part is "as many as you like" since you can make them as small as you like.

Comment: What work have you done yourself? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question isn't complete. since you can make them as small as you like , the response will be infinity
Althought if we choose each time the biggest rectangle possible (satisfying the criteria) the answer will be 5
(300*150 , 60*120 , 60*120, 60*30 , 60*30)

Comment: question edited.

Comment: then the answer will be my first rectangle 
300*150